# drop down menu not appearing in the following php code, but every other element is in the table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm using php to create a table from the data extracted from MySQL database. I'm using `SELECT * From table_name` and all data is appearing as I wish. But I want to create a Drop Down menu in the last column for that I'm using the function `displayDMenu`. But the drop down menu is still not appearing in the table. Can you please suggest what is causing the problem and solution? Or alternate solutions? Here's the code:

```
<div id="main">
<?php
include("config.php");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM schedule");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Appoint No.</th>
<th>CR number</th>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Month</th>
<th>Year</th>
<th>Department</th>
<th>Status</th>

</tr>";


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td style='padding:3px'>" . $row['S_ID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td style='padding:3px'>" . $row['crnumber'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td style='padding:3px'>" . $row['ScdTime'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td style='padding:3px'>" . $row['ScdDate'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td style='padding:3px'>" . $row['ScdMonth'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td style='padding:3px'>" . $row['ScdYear'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td style='padding:3px'>" . $row['DName'] . "</td>";

 echo "<td 'style='padding:3px'>" . displayDMenu() . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
    echo "</table>";
function displayDMenu() {
    $r = '';
    $r .='<form method="post" action="ScdApproval.php">';
    $r .='<select name="Status">';
    $r .='<option value="approved" selected>Approve</option>';
    $r .='<option value="disapproved">Disapprove</option>';
    $r .='</select>';
    $r .='</form>';
}

?>
</div> <!--main ends here -->
```

Comment: Whats `echo "</table>";` doing in the while loop?

Comment: Oh that was a mistake that I put here. corrected. The menu is still not showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you need the user function its not doing anything logical its just spitting back html which there is no reason not to put that html in the while loop.

```
<?php 
include("config.php");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM schedule");
?>
<style>#main table tr td{padding:3px;}</style>
<div id="main">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Appoint No.</th>
            <th>CR number</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Month</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
        <?php 
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0): 
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)): ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $row['S_ID']?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['crnumber']?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['ScdTime']?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['ScdDate']?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['ScdMonth']?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['ScdYear']?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['DName']?></td>
          <td><form method="post" action="ScdApproval.php">
                 <select name="Status">
                 <option value="approved" selected>Approve</option>
                 <option value="disapproved">Disapprove</option>
                 </select>
               </form>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
        endwhile;
        else: ?>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="8">No results</td>
        </tr>
        <?php endif;?>
    </table>
</div> <!--main ends here -->
```

Also:
Really you should also switch to using PDO or mysqli prepared querys for new code.

Comment: Thank you, it solved the problem. Now if I need to submit all the choices from the drop down menu, a simple submit button would send all data? (not just the drop down menu selections but all other info like date, time etc.) or I need to do something else?

Comment: A button will be specific for the form its in. If you add a button at the bottom of your table and want to submit all the values within the table then you need to wrap the whole table in a form and just have the select input within your while loop, also you will need to add hidden values for the other values, and `<select name="Status">` would have to be an array like `<select name="Status[]">` plus your PHP would need to handle the posted array not a single value **big changes** alternatively you could use AJAX to submit/update the row onChange.

Comment: I only know a little bit about AJAX. Can you please point me to a tutorial that would be useful? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the value $r in the function displayDMenu()

ie

```
function displayDMenu()
{
   .........
   return $r;
}
```